# How to set the sharding `region` to avoid reporting `AsyncIoTConsensusServiceClient 113` type error in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Is sharding `region` of Apache IoTDB based on time sharding? How can I reduce the quantity of this `region`? I think there are too many of this, so I got this error reported, but if I set this quantity too small, the writing performance cannot keep up. The error message looks like this: `[AsyncDataNodeloTConsensusServiceClientPool-selector-120] INFO o.a.i.c.i.c.AsyncIoTConsensusServiceClient: 113 - Unexpected exception occurs in AsyncConfigNodeIServiceClient{TEndPoint(ip:192.168.242.135, port:10760)}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Client has an error`. Anyone know how to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the number of `region` of Apache IoTDB through these two parameters: `default_data_region_group_num_per_database` and `data_region_per_data_node`. You can increase the `rpc` timeout (such as to half an hour) and then restart IoTDB. This problem will be alleviated. Or you can update your IoTDB version, since the new 1.3.0 version will no longer report this error.